# Error while connecting: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

[image]

What do I do when i get this message? I can't join any servers at all!

Comment: Were you able to connect to servers before? Is Minecraft, i.e. `javaw.exe` allowed through the firewall? (Make sure it's the correct `javaw.exe` as Minecraft comes with it's own runtime on Windows!)

Comment: I was able to connect before. Its allowed but still cant join :(

Comment: I had the same problem, but I don't know how I solved it. Does the problem persist after restaring MC or the PC?

Comment: Its still here :( i tryed to unistall mc ir install and still not working :(

Answer (score -2):

Easy, just press shift twice and then hit R and E at the same time. This only works on a computer or iPad/iPod/iPhone. It always works for me. It's either a glitch on Minecraft, or a glitch on *my* iPad, so this may not work for you.

Comment: Its not working, still servers wont work :(